# Jenkins slave node is offline: Password authentication failed

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops

I created a base image for Jenkins slave agent on Centos8

```
FROM centos:8

# Install Essentials
RUN sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*  && \
    sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*  && \
    yum update -y && \
    yum clean all

# Install a basic SSH server GIT, UNZIP, LSOF and JDK 8
RUN yum install -y openssh-server git unzip lsof java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless && yum clean all
# update sshd settings, create jenkins user, set jenkins user pw, generate ssh keys
RUN sed -i 's|session    required     pam_loginuid.so|session    optional     pam_loginuid.so|g' /etc/pam.d/sshd \
    && mkdir -p /var/run/sshd \
    && useradd -u 1000 -m -s /bin/bash jenkins \
    && echo "jenkins:jenkins" | chpasswd \
    && /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A \
    && echo export JAVA_HOME="/`alternatives  --display java | grep best | cut -d "/" -f 2-6`" >> /etc/environment

# Set java environment
ENV JAVA_HOME /etc/alternatives/jre

# Standard SSH port
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Create cloud.
Configured docker agent template.
Create Credentials jenkins/jenkins in global scope.

Indicated the connection method:
[image]

but when I run job I get an error: All nodes of label ‘docker-slave’ are offline

in logs of docker-slave i see:

```
[12/27/23 08:46:42] [SSH] WARNING: SSH Host Keys are not being verified. Man-in-the-middle attacks may be possible against this connection.
ERROR: Unexpected error while trying to authenticate as jenkins with credential=docker-slave
java.io.IOException: Password authentication failed.
    at com.trilead.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.authenticatePassword(AuthenticationManager.java:404)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.authenticateWithPassword(Connection.java:340)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.TrileadSSHPasswordAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(TrileadSSHPasswordAuthenticator.java:115)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.SSHAuthenticator.authenticate(SSHAuthenticator.java:431)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.SSHAuthenticator.authenticate(SSHAuthenticator.java:468)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:865)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$1.call(SSHLauncher.java:436)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$1.call(SSHLauncher.java:423)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The connection is closed.
    at com.trilead.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.deQueue(AuthenticationManager.java:72)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.getNextMessage(AuthenticationManager.java:100)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.authenticatePassword(AuthenticationManager.java:379)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot read full block, EOF reached.
    at com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherInputStream.getBlock(CipherInputStream.java:81)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:108)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportConnection.receiveMessage(TransportConnection.java:232)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:706)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:502)
    ... 1 more
[12/27/23 08:46:42] [SSH] Authentication failed.
Authentication failed.
[12/27/23 08:46:42] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[12/27/23 08:46:42] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Comment: The error says `Password authentication failed`. There is some issue with the authentication, so start by checking that if you believe that your credentials are correct.

Comment: @MB I tried to enter an incorrect password in my credentials. in this case an error appears: Failed to authenticate as jenkins. Wrong password. with correct credentials i get: Unexpected error while trying to authenticate as jenkins with credential=docker-slave
java.io.IOException: Password authentication failed